# Alternatives to RDBMS For Forecast Data

Tags: database-design, nosql

I currently capture well structured forecast data in a SQL Server.  An example of this data is below:

[image: Sample Data]

What this tells me is that each day, I receive a forecast for the next three days. Note that in the real world, I may receive a forecast each hour (DateOfForecast) for the next 48 hours ('DateInQuestion') at 15 minute granularity.

How do I use this data?  There are several use-cases, all with subtle but important differences.  I'll go through them below.

**Best (Latest) Data**

If I want best data, this is the most recent forecast for each 'DateInQuestion'.  So my best data for January would look like:

[image: Best Data]

Note that in real world, the DateOfForecast may not be regular and may be more than once per day

**At A Point in Time**

This is where I want to see what the data looked like at a specific point in time.  In example below, I'm showing what the data looked like on the 2nd of January.

[image: Point in Time]

**Specific Forecast**

I will skip the screenshot here - this would show the forecast created, for example, on the 2nd of January and would show all records where the 'DateOfForecast' is 2nd January.

**Rolling Window**

In this case, I present 'what was the best data available 2 or more days before each 'DateInQuestion', giving:

[image: Rolling WIndow]

That covers the majority of scenarios.  Some volumes:

- If we think of the example forecast above as one data set (let's say it's temperature forecasts for London), I have several hundred thousand data sets. Each data set has a unique (artificial) key
- The description (meta) for each data set is stored in a separate system and need not be repeated in any replacement.
- The frequency of publication (number of forecasts per day) can be between 1 and approximately 48.
- I may have 10 years or more history for any given data set, none of which may be archived
- The horizon (how far out being forecasted for) can vary between one hour and one year.
- The granularity (length of period in DateInQuestion) can be anything from 1 minute to one month.  It is, however, consistent within a dataset.
- In my current RDBMS database, I have around 2TB of data.
- Horizon of data retrieval by query, for any example above, can be from one period (DateInQuestion) to several years.

**Problems with current system**
 - Slowing down due to vertical scaling constraints
 - Several of the query use cases I have presented represent rather non-efficient query executions

So, leading on to my question!! I have being looking into NoSQL databases generally (i.e. not focussing on a single implementation). However, most case studies I have came across follow a more '[date,value]' structure and do not address the query use cases I have mentioned.

1. Does this data lend itself well to NoSQL?
2. Can you suggest an object design for NoSQL?

Please comment if any of the above is unclear and I will try to clarify.

**Update 1**
Any future database can be either 'on-prem', AWS or Azure.
It must be usable from a variety of technologies such as .Net, Excel and Python.  Obviously I can provide an API layer to address this if needed.

Comment: I'm not a DB expert, but to me those queries sound like an RDBMS should be able to handle them just fine. I don't see what a NoSQL DB would give you here. Can you give more detail on what makes the queries so slow (if this question is still relevant at all)?

Comment: I would not expect a NoSQL DB to be more appropriate than an RDBMS for this, quite the opposite. Proper indexing and denormalization are the standard tools to solve performance problems in such a system. Especially denormalization, since such kind of data consists usually of immutable records, which means denormalization won't lead to consistency issues.

Comment: NoSQL databases have their own woes. Namely transactions. They just do not exist in any convient form (they they do *"exist"*). These systems do offer atomic document updates/insert/remove presuming a single db server. However many of them will offer only eventual consistency in a multi-node system. Eventual consistency is ignorable when everything is reliable and consistent - I've yet to meet such a system in production though. Which means your program will be responsible for enforcing consistency accross all of its operations.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Unless you've already tried very hard to optimize your SQL database (checking indices, looking at query execution plans, etc, etc) and found that *doesn't* fix the problem, that's that first thing you should be doing before saying "I need to move to NoSQL".